# Resized images not smooth in flex

Tags: image-processing, image

I am loading images in flex 3.0 , but when they are resized they look grainy and distortered . Can i give some sort of effect or dsomething to fix this .thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to load image as bitmap and **apply smoothing** to it .I have implemented this in my slide show. I found code snipet from this link , hope this is what you want

http://askmeflash.com/article/4/smoothing-resized-distorted-images-in-flex

Answer (score 1):

[Try this site. Flex Monkey Patches](http://blog.flexmonkeypatches.com/2007/02/05/scaling-an-image-with-smoothing/)